# Disable Copy/Paste

Tags: excel, vba

Disabled copy paste in Excel is working with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(Allow As Boolean)
    Call EnableMenuItem(21, Allow)
    Call EnableMenuItem(19, Allow)
    Call EnableMenuItem(22, Allow)
    Call EnableMenuItem(755, Allow)
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = Allow
    With Application
        Select Case Allow
            Case Is = False
                .OnKey "^c", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
                .OnKey "^v", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
                .OnKey "^x", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
                .OnKey "+{DEL}", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
                .OnKey "^{INSERT}", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
            Case Is = True
                .OnKey "^c"
                .OnKey "^v"
                .OnKey "^x"
                .OnKey "+{DEL}"
                .OnKey "^{INSERT}"
            End Select
    End With
End Sub
Sub EnableMenuItem(ctlId As Integer, Enabled As Boolean)
    Dim cBar As CommandBar
    Dim cBarCtrl As CommandBarControl
    For Each cBar In Application.CommandBars
        If cBar.Name <> "Clipboard" Then
            Set cBarCtrl = cBar.FindControl(ID:=ctlId, recursive:=True)
            If Not cBarCtrl Is Nothing Then cBarCtrl.Enabled = Enabled
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub CutCopyPasteDisabled()
    MsgBox "Sorry!  Cutting, copying and pasting have been disabled in this workbook!"
End Sub
```

but when I double-click into a cell and then I can do anything there cut, copy and paste.

How to disable copy paste even double-click into a cell?

Comment: please, don't !  copy-paste is the most supportive user operation. And you probably won't prevent it anyway

Comment: almost always there are hacker ways to extract the text

Comment: Yes, but i need it for some time purposely. And the above code is working. Only i can't prevent when using double click. Normally its showing disabled only its not working after double click into a cell.

Comment: Check out sample file for ur information http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can protect your worksheets with [`Worksheet.Protect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx), for example:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect "Password"
```

Now the user is not able to select nor change values in the cells.
You also can lock the cells [manually](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-cells-to-protect-them-54fedd95-28dc-4abc-a26c-6566917c1a59).

You can also [`Unprotect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff841143.aspx) the worksheet:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "Password"
```

this you will need to do before you change the worksheet (also through VBA).

**Edit 1**: I don't know how to let the user still edit cells, but not copy-paste their values. Another 'solution' to this could be to let the user input the data through a form. As an example I added a button to the sheet:

[image: add excel button]

(Note: if you can't see the Developer tab, [you will have to add it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx).) Now you will be asked which macro to assign to it, choose *New*. Now you can fill the sub (macro) assigned to the button with the following code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "Password"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = InputBox("New value")
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect "Password"
End Sub
```

Now the user is only able to change the value of that cell, in this example A1.

Comment: @aglod, thanks for your reply. My requirement is user can edit and add any text into any cell. I just want to disable copy paste. Users can't copy, paste into the sheet.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get clear. Can u pls add any sample worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

This might help?

Enter this on the Thisworkbook (Code) page

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Double click disabled!"
End Sub
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSraj.jpg]

Comment: When the user limits or disabls the VBA in his Excel application - wouldn't this be ignored?